# Room LiveData, ViewModel. Search by name. Strange filtering behavior

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-room

When you click on the search button, it activity with a full list of items. At the top is editText and when the user starts typing the name, the list should be dynamically filtered. I only master Architecture Components and it seems like I managed to implement a search, but it works crookedly.

Suppose the following names: "magic", "summer", "salt", "spark" and so on. I start typing "s" - the list changes, only the words with this letter remain. Then I enter "a", the word "salt" should remain, but nothing changes. When I erase typed, the list is not updated. Help solve the problem.

DataDao

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM Data WHERE title LIKE :search")
LiveData<List<Data>> getAllSearch(String search);
```

DataRepository

```
    public class DataRepository {
private DatabaseCopier db;
private DataDao dataDao;

DataRepository(Application application) {
    db = DatabaseCopier.getInstance(application);
    dataDao = db.getDatabase().dataDao();
}

LiveData<List<Data>> getAllSearch(String search) {
    return db.getDatabase().dataDao().getAllSearch(search);
}
```

ViewModel with a factory, where I pass the name to the constructor.

```
 public class DataViewModelSearch extends AndroidViewModel {
private LiveData<List<Data>> currentData;
private DataRepository repository;

public DataViewModelSearch(@NonNull Application application, final String dataTitle) {
    super(application);
    String verseTitle = dataTitle;
    repository = new DataRepositorySearch(application);
    currentData = repository.getAllSearch(verseTitle);
}

public LiveData<List<Data>> getAllSearch() {
    return currentData;
}

    public static class ModelFactorySearch extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory {
        @NonNull
        private final Application application;
        private final String dataTitle;
        private final DataRepository repository;

        public ModelFactorySearch(@NonNull Application application, String title) {
            super();
            this.application = application;
            this.dataTitle = title;
            repository = new DataRepository(application);
        }

        @NonNull
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
            if (modelClass == DataViewModel.class) {
                return (T) new DataViewModelSearch(application, dataTitle);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

SearchActivity

```
 public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private SearchAdapter adapter;
RvObserver observer;
EditText etFilter;
RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    observer = new RvObserver();
    etFilter = findViewById(R.id.et_filter);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_search);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    dividerItemDecoration.setDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.divider));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
    adapter = new SearchAdapter(onSearchClickListener, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    DataListViewModel dataListViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(DataListViewModel.class);
    dataListViewModel.getAllVersesABS().observe(this, new Observer<List<Data>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Data> data) {
            adapter.setData(data);
        }
    });

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle(1);
    bundle.putString("filter", "");


    etFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            refresh(charSequence.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }

    });
}


private void refresh(String searchText) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle(1);
    bundle.putString("filter", searchText);

    searchText = "%" + searchText + "%";
    final DataViewModelSearch.ModelFactorySearch factory = new DataViewModelSearch.ModelFactorySearch(
            getApplication(), searchText);

    final DataViewModelSearch modelSearch = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory)
            .get(DataViewModelSearch.class);

    modelSearch.getAllSearch().observe(this, new Observer<List<Data>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Data> data) {
            adapter.setData(data);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(observer);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    adapter.unregisterAdapterDataObserver(observer);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have problem in your refreshing logic. Every time when you type something you create new ViewModel with new Repository.

Second, you use LiveData as async work tool, but LiveData triggers when you change something in your database. However, you don't change data and just want to perform SQL query. That is why I use AsyncTask in example(for simplicity). You can use RxJava.

Here is simple example.

SearchActivity

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private SearchAdapter adapter;
private DataViewModelSearch dataListViewModel;
EditText etFilter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    etFilter = findViewById(R.id.et_filter);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_search);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adapter = new SearchAdapter(onSearchClickListener, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    dataListViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(DataListViewModel.class);
    dataListViewModel.searchData.observe(this, new Observer<List<Data>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Data> data) {
            adapter.setData(data); // it will be triggered every time when we change searchData in ViewModel via searchData.setValue()
        }
    });

    etFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            dataListViewModel.refresh(charSequence.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }

    });
}
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class DataViewModelSearch extends AndroidViewModel {

MutableLiveData<List<Data>> searchData = new MutableLiveData<>();

private DataRepository repository;

public DataViewModelSearch(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    repository = new DataRepositorySearch(application); // better create repos outside viewModel or activity, but this is for example
}

private void refresh(String searchText) {
    String formattedSearchText = "%" + searchText + "%";
    new GetSearchDataTask.execute(formattedSearchText)
}

//for Async Work
private class GetSearchDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Data>> {

        @Override
        protected List<Data> doInBackground(String... params) {
            return repository.getAllSearch(params[0])
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Data> data) {
            super.onPostExecute(data); 
            searchData.setValue(data); //change LiveData value
        }
    }


}
```

Your repository should return `List<Data> getAllSearch(String search);`

Comment: Hey. The search works correctly, but I needed so that when I clicked on the search button, the entire list was displayed, and when I entered the name, what was needed remained. And with this implementation, an empty screen opens and the search does not work dynamically. Could you tell me how to do this?

Comment: Just make onClicklistener and make `dataListViewModel.refresh("");` And then your LIKE parametr will look "%%". That should return all results

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question. I do not understand on what the listener should hang

Comment: As I understood, you said when you click on  search button you want to show all results, so you need to set listener to search biutton